# How to get scanf to Reject a new line

Tags: c, stdin

So I'm just doing a basic enter a number between 1 and 10 game. I have finally managed to get everything going right after a lot of messing around.
The final piece of the puzzle is that at the moment if you press enter without any other input it just makes a new line instead of re prompting like I want.

Basically my code is this at the moment:

```
int guess = 0;

ungetc('\n', stdin);

do
{
    while((guess = getchar()) != '\n' && guess != EOF);
    printf("Please type a integer value between and inclusive of 1 and 10: \n");

}while(scanf("%d", &guess) != 1 || guess < 0 || guess > 10);
```

All I want is that it loops again if you hit enter and nothing else, but I can't for the life of me work this out.

Comment: Consider using `fgets` and `sscanf` instead of `scanf`

Comment: That is because `scanf` blocks waiting for input and pressing `[Enter]` by itself does not constitute input when you are looking for an integer.

Comment: Should the condition in the while be `guess < 1` rather than `guess < 0`?

Answer (score 2):

You can really make things hard on yourself using `scanf` for integer input if you don't want `scanf` to simply block waiting for valid input. `fgets` and `sscanf` are far easier.

However, you can do it with `scanf` (and `getchar` and `ungetc`), and it is instructive to work though the process.

To begin with, the general approach (as you have taken) is to loop continually until you receive valid input or the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF` (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> on windoze).

To prevent `scanf` from blocking, you need to pre-read from `stdin` to trap the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> without any additional input. The simple way is to simply `getchar()` and test if the character is `'\n'`, or `EOF`, or it there is a character for input, which you then put back in `stdin` with `ungetc` and proceed with the `scanf` conversion to `int` (you can let `scanf` handle the *matching* or *input* failures at this point.

Putting it altogether, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int guess;

    for (;;) {  /* loop until valid input or user cancels */

        int c, rtn;     /* char for getchar(), return for scanf */

        printf ("enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]: "); /* prompt */

        if ((c = getchar()) == '\n')    /* did the user press [Enter]? */
            continue;                   /* redisplay prompt */
        else if (c == EOF) {            /* did user cancel input? */
            fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n"); /* bail */
            return 0;
        }
        else {  /* otherwise validate putting char back in stdin */
            if (ungetc (c, stdin) != c) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: ungetc failed.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &guess);      /* save scanf return */

        /* validate return and input range */
        if (rtn != 1 || guess < 1 || 10 < guess) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            for (c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
        }
        else
            break;  /* we have a good value */
    }

    printf ("good guess: %d\n", guess);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you are free to warn of *invalid input* on the `'\n'`, but simply re-displaying the prompt is sufficient)

**Example Use/Output**

With the user hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> three-times before inputting the first character.

```
$ ./bin/scanfguess
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]:
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]:
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]:
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]: a
error: invalid input.
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]: -1
error: invalid input.
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]: 1
good guess: 1
```

Or where the user generates an `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>:

```
$ ./bin/scanfguess
enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]: user canceled input.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions -- then go re-implement the logic with `fgets` and `sscanf` (much simpler). For example, you could replace the code above with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 256

int main (void) {

    int guess;

    for (;;) {  /* loop until valid input or user cancels */

        char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer for fgets */

        printf ("enter an integer [1-10 inclusive]: "); /* prompt */

        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n"); /* bail */
            return 0;        
        }

        /* perfom conversion to int and validate range */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &guess) != 1 || guess < 1 || guess > 10)
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        else    /* we have a good value */
            break;
    }

    printf ("good guess: %d\n", guess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, there is so much good info there. Yea, I realised early on that there were probably much better and easier ways to doing this, but apart from being stubborn I found it very insightful in how the buffer and stdio was working (this is just for learning rather than any sort of project I need to finish) and how to properly branch and validate input. So it's been a good experience and your reply has certainly helped a lot!

Comment: Yep, that the best way to learn. Go figure out all the ways you can be bitten by `scanf`, and what is left over it the proper way to do it. `scanf` is really just a character accounting problem. Knowing what *format specifiers* ignore whitespace (the numeric conversions) and which don't (character conversions) and then figuring out what is left in `stdin` after a valid conversion, and also what's there after a failure. Treat it that way, and you will have no problems using it. Skip the accounting, and you are doomed to be bitten.